# Esp8285 not working

Tags: pcb-design, esp8266

[image]

Hi my custom board for esp8285 isn't working, does anyone has idea what went wrong? I'm looking for error in schematic

Comment: Could be a million things. What have you checked?

Comment: I checked all solder joints and traces, measured all pasive components, power supply voltage, for me it looks like some error in my design.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.